# UIScrollView Category utility function for auto sizing contentSize

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-runtime

I wanted a utility function on UIScrollView to automatically size the contentSize based on the content inside the scrollView. How is this?

```
#import "UIScrollView+UIScrollViewUtilities.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static const int BOTTOM_CONTENT_OFFSET = 75;

@implementation UIScrollView (UIScrollViewUtilities)

- (void)setRecursiveSubviews:(NSMutableArray *)recursiveSubviews {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(recursiveSubviews), recursiveSubviews, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (NSMutableArray *)recursiveSubviews {
    NSMutableArray *array = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(recursiveSubviews));
    if (array == nil) {
        array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self setRecursiveSubviews:array];
    }
    return array;
}

- (void)autoAdjustContentSize {
    [self autoAdjustContentSize:self];
}

/*
 * This method is used to dynamically set the contentSize
 * of a UIScrollView based on its content.
 */
- (void)autoAdjustContentSize:(UIView *)view {

    // For all subviews of view passed in, add them to our
    // recursiveSubviews array and call this method recursively
    // to ensure we add all subviews (even grandchildren subviews)
    for (UIView *subView in [view subviews]) {
        NSMutableArray *array = [self recursiveSubviews];
        [array addObject:subView];
        [self setRecursiveSubviews:array];

        [self autoAdjustContentSize:subView];
    }

    // Of all of our subviews found, figure out which one
    // is the bottom-most element, and remember its y val
    CGFloat currentBottomValue = 0;
    for (UIView *subView in [self recursiveSubviews]) {
        CGFloat thisElementsBottomValue = subView.frame.origin.y + subView.frame.size.height;

        // Ignore UIViews because they are just blank space by themselves
        if (![subView isMemberOfClass:[UIView class]] && thisElementsBottomValue > currentBottomValue) {
            currentBottomValue = thisElementsBottomValue;
        }
    }

    // Finally, update the contentSize of the scrollView based on the bottom most element found on screen
    [self setContentSize:CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, currentBottomValue + BOTTOM_CONTENT_OFFSET)];
}

@end
```

Comment: Why don't you just use auto-layout?

Comment: @nhgrif I do use auto-layout. There is a way to auto size the contentSize property of a UIScrollView with auto-layout? I'm not aware of that.

Comment: I believe so. Tomorrow I will take a look

Comment: I think the trick is to add all of your stuff to a new `UIView` (which you can size with auto-resizing constraints), then add that `UIView` to the scrollview.  So the scroll view's content view has exactly one subview, and then it should work correctly.

Comment: @nhgrif I think you are right. I think I can set the UIView's height to be based on the bottom most element in storyboard which should accomplish the same functionality using auto-layout with no code. I'll try it out later.

Comment: [Here](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/) is a good tutorial on how to do this with auto layout.